# Getting Error While trying to Setup MySql Datasource in JBOSS EAP 7.4

Tags: mysql, jboss-eap-7

Getting the below mentioned error everytime I run the server.

```
 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "MySqlDS")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql",
        "jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]",
        "org.wildfly.data-source.MySqlDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]",
        "org.wildfly.data-source.MySqlDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]"
    ]
}
```

I am trying to setup MySql datasource with JNDI in JBOSS EAP 7.4.
I have created the module.xml and put the mysql-connector jar inside com/mysql/main folder.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.9" name="com.mysql">
      <properties>
          <property name="jboss.api" value="unsupported"/>
       </properties>

   <resources>
        <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar"/>
   </resources>
      
 <dependencies>
     <module name="javax.api"/>  
     <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
     <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
 </dependencies>
 
</module>
```

Also have added the datasource details in standalone.xml file and also added the driver in driver tags.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:6.0">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS" pool-name="MySqlDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                            <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookshopdb</connection-url>
                             <driver-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                             <driver>mysql</driver>
                            <new-connection-sql>SELECT 1</new-connection-sql>
                            <pool>
                                 <min-pool-size>0</min-pool-size>
                                 <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
                                 <flush-strategy>IdleConnections</flush-strategy>
                            </pool>
                            <security>
                                    <user-name>root</user-name>
                                    <password>root</password>
                            </security>
                            <validation>
                                    <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
                                    <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
                            </validation>
                </datasource>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" statistics-enabled="${wildfly.datasources.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
                    <driver>h2</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>sa</user-name>
                        <password>sa</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                           <driver-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                          <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                     </driver>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
```